# Emit mapper and Generic method

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, emitmapper

I have some problem with Emit mapper when I try to save in database properties. 
In first I mapped this class (it work good):

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileProperty 
{
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public ProfileProperty(string value, bool isVisible = true)
    {
        this.PropertyValue = value;
        this.IsVisible = isVisible;
    }

    public ProfileProperty()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

I mapped here:

```
var mapper = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<PollmericaProfile, ProfileModel>();
ProfileModel prof = new ProfileModel();
if (x.User != null)
{
    prof = mapper.Map(x);
}
```

But some of the requirements need not a `string` property. That's why I decided to write this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileProperty 
{
    public object PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public ProfileProperty(object value, bool isVisible = true)
    {
        this.PropertyValue = value;
        this.IsVisible = isVisible;
    }

    public ProfileProperty()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public T GetValue<T>()
    {
        return (T)this.PropertyValue;
    }
}
```

And all mapping is not worked =( 
If you ccan, help me please. If you want I can provide the necessary information. 

P.S. To be honest, I want to transfer to a string and back, so at least works

UPD: I tried without method `public T GetValue<T>()`... It works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for this, but I find answer very quicly. 
in mapping I must to write this:

```
var mapper = ObjectMapperManager
               .DefaultInstance
               .GetMapper<PollmericaProfile, ProfileModel>( new DefaultMapConfig()
               .IgnoreMembers<PollmericaProfile, ProfileModel>(new string[] { "GetValue" }));
ProfileModel prof = new ProfileModel();
if (x.User != null)
{
    prof = mapper.Map(x);
}
```